# Xamarin IOS CollectionView: cannot vertically align items

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm using CollectionView with DataTemplate

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="tileTemplate">
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  BackgroundColor="Red" Padding="5" x:Name="ItemContainer">
        <StackLayout Padding="5" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" WidthRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference ItemContainer}}" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference ItemContainer}}">
        <Image Source="{Binding LogoID}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFit" />
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</DataTemplate>


<CollectionView x:Name="ItemsCollectionView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource itemsDataTemplateSelector}">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"/>
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
</CollectionView>
```

On Android they align vertically from the top:

[image]

But on IOS they align rather chaotically:

[image]

I can't figure out how to align them from the top like in Android.

**--== UPDATE ==-- :**

The problem is with HeightRequest of inner StackLayout

> HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference ItemContainer}}"

(same result if you use OnSizeAllocated)

```
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
    base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
    
    HeightRequest = Width;
}
```

How to keep proportions and prevent tiles from popping on IOS is still opened question.

Comment: Can you post code inside stacklayout?

Answer (score 1):

It may caused by the layout in your stacklayout, I wrote a sample and it works well in iOS:

```
<CollectionView >
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="3"/>
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
            <x:String>Baboon</x:String>
            <x:String>Capuchin Monkey Capuchin MonkeyCapuchin MonkeyCapuchin MonkeyCapuchin MonkeyCapuchin MonkeyCapuchin MonkeyCapuchin Monkey</x:String>
            <x:String>Blue Monkey</x:String>
        </x:Array>
    </CollectionView.ItemsSource>

    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Red">
                <Frame BackgroundColor="Green" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="90">
                    <Image Source="Images.png"/>
                </Frame>
                <Label Text="{Binding .}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

[image]

Comment: With this example I found out the problem: it was element inside top StackLayout, which changed size on OnSizeAllocated:  

protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
  {
   base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);

   HeightRequest = Width;
  }  

to make tiles perfectly square. And that causes vertical shifiting on IOS. How to solve that still a mystery.

Comment: Can you please share us a Minimal, Reproducible Example? I use your code and it all works well on my side. Share us the ItemContainer class and all the layout inside the StackLayout(where is the label?).

Comment: I have updated the post, the inner StackLayout (white area) HeightRequest binded to parent StackLayout (red area) height to make it square. Data in collection view is irrelevant.        Alternatively instead of binding we can create custom StackLayout with single override:  protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height) { base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height); HeightRequest = Width; } and use it instead of white StackLayout (inner one), it leads to same result.

Comment: N.B. I have noticed that setting ItemSizingStrategy to MeasureFirstItem stick them to top as intended, but if height of text under first element is smaller, bigger elements are overlapped by items in the next row (as the height of all items renders equal to the first element)

Comment: I upload a sample project [here](https://github.com/XfHua/Xamarin-CollectionView-Xaml) and can you check what I'm missing? The only difference is I set `Span="3"` in the `GridItemsLayout `.

Comment: Thank you for the sample, I've created [pull request](https://github.com/XfHua/Xamarin-CollectionView-Xaml/pull/1) to reproduce that bug. I moved CollectionView source to ViewModel's ObservableCollection

Answer (score 0):

Try using StartAndExpand instead of FillAndExpand on the StackLayouts VerticalOptions

Comment: Tried it, everything is ignored